# My install (UBUNTU Precise) has No print drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

I have UBUNTU Precise to run LINUX-CNC.
I want to print setting sheets etc. on my BROTHER HL1470N network printer.
The install Printer page finds the printer, but hangs when looking for the driver.
on investigation I found the etc/cups/ppd folder empty.
Can I download and install them using apt get install?, if so what syntax.
I have an up to date KUBUNTU computer that uses this printer via my home network with no bother at all. If I copied this file, how do I install it on my UBUNTU Precise PC?

Comment: Try using [the printer driver that Brother provides.](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl1470n_all&os=128)

Answer (score 0):

With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-common
```

The driver for the HL-1470N should now be available.